# YouTube Video Not Loading on Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, video, mobile, youtube, youtube-api

I am using a footage for my website and i have upload it to the YouTube. My video must autoplay when page loaded and loop after finished, so i have used YT Api to achive it. Problem is, when i use mobile device emulation of Google Chrome, video does the trick prefectly but when i try to load my page in an actual mobile device, YouTube try to load video and after a while my vide timeout and it is warning me about rebooting my phone (no idea why, may best guess is it is a translation error).

Here is the code i have been using:

**HTML**

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
        <div id="player"></div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'XCZMvZBKClM',
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'showinfo': 0 },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

var done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        player.playVideo();
    }
}
function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
}
```

And probably not related but **CSS**

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: black;
}

.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}

    .videoWrapper iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

As a detail, when i touch to video it goes full-screen and streaming starts normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoplaying video/audio is impossible on mobile devices.

It's a plague introduced by Apple and since copied by most mobile browsers.

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it. This means the JavaScript play() and load() methods are also inactive until the user initiates playback, unless the play() or load() method is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play button works, but an onLoad="play()" event does not.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

Comment: I was aware of that we cant use autoplay=1 feature on mobile devices but was hoping that YT Api would make it work. You are probably right, but i am going to wait for some alternative ideas.

Comment: The YT Api makes it even worse, because the <video> element is inside an iframe. This means you can't even use hacks like calling play on the first `touchstart` of the page, because the play command is sent to the iframe using `postMessage` and it still won't play. The user **has** to touch the video inside the iframe.